# CSS: Transition timing help, span filling containing element and dynamic(?) width

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with some navigation effects for a project and I've hit a few problems I'm afraid.

Firstly, the transition timing seems a bit off. My general desire was to have the "tooltip", or link name/label, to slide out when you hover over, and then slide back in when you hover off. The idea was to have the highlight color of the icon (numbers in this case) to appear as though it's simply extending and revealing the word, and then shrinking until it's all gone. I've tried a number of variations of timing and delays, but no luck.

I'm also having issues with getting the span to fill the available space/same height of the link area. I altered the spans color to highlight this discrepancy in area.

Lastly, I've put a longer name for link 5 to demonstrate the limitation/problem with using a fixed/specific width for the span. I don't think there's anyway to achieve all that I'm hoping to as well as having a variable width that depends on the length of the text.

Here is the code I have (CodePen link below):
HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="navigation navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navigation container">
            <ul class="navigation nav-left">
                <li><a href="#">1<span class="tooltiptext">Welcome</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2<span class="tooltiptext">Second</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3<span class="tooltiptext">Third</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4<span class="tooltiptext">Fourth</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5<span class="tooltiptext">ExtraLongOneToExposeProblem</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6<span class="tooltiptext">Sixth</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation::after {
    clear: both;
}

.navigation::before, .navigation::after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.container::after {
    clear: both;
}

.container::before, .container::after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.navigation {
    min-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .navigation > li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

.nav-right, .nav-right > li {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-left, .nav-left > li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: sticky;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

    .navbar-fixed-top::before {
        display: block;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        top: -142px;
        background-color: #008ed0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(0, 87, 128), rgb(0, 157, 230));
    }

.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.tooltiptext {
    display: block;
    background-color: #008ed0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1001;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.navigation li:hover .tooltiptext {
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}

body {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

ul, ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li > a {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

    fill: white;
}

    li > a:hover, li > a:focus {
        background-color: #d50f67;
        color: white;

        fill: white;
    }

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Linking to this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/zabojcagwiazd/pen/aQGoeY/) in the hopes someone can help.

Kind regards,
Don

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to transition to `auto` width and that's not possible with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry if "width: auto" was left in there at some point, when you happened to look, that was just me playing around with settings, the current version(s) of it with "width: 150px" are what I'm working with